# Custom Form Response

Tags: custom-form

I have created a custom contact form for our physicians to be able to contact our IT team with comments and questions. However, after they submit the form, it goes back to the list with the information. They do not need to be able to see other users entries. Is there a way to revert them back to the homepage, or have a screen that says "Thanks for contacting us..."?

I appreciate any thoughts or advice.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't clear on how they are getting to your form. If they are using a hyperlink or button from some SitePage or something like that, you can do it by altering your url to the form.

You'd add `?Source=http://domain.com/sites/sites/pages/thankyou.aspx` where thankyou.aspx is a page you created that you'd like to redirect them to. So altogether, you'd have something like:

`http://domain.com/sites/sites/lists/list/forms/customnewform.aspx?Source=http://domain.com/sites/sites/pages/thankyou.aspx`

There are other ways to do it involving script or further customizations, but this is the most straightforward approach.